# WP Rest API- POST request for images returns as empty brackets [ ]

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Iam new to php so I would appreciate your help.

Below code provides for rest api responses for taxonomy, metafields and gallery/image field.

When i issue a POST request via API, the image field returns as empty while the taxonomy and other meta fields return new value as expected.

As can be seen from below response json, the return value is `[]`

InputJson

```
{"Taxonomy1":[445],"meta":{'field1':'55'},"Imagefield":['/home/Imagefolder/1.jpeg']}
```

ResponseJson

```
{"Taxonomy1":[445],"meta":{'field1':'55'},"Imagefield":[]}
```

Note: Imagefield is instance of GalleryField

I cant see why the Imagefield gives empty field (`[]`). Is there anything that sticks out in the below code that needs to be edited?
Any advise?

```
<?php

namespace Dehaka\Managers;

use Dehaka\Core\Manager;
use Dehaka\Model\Post\Car;
use Dehaka\Model\Post\Field\AttachmentsField;
use Dehaka\Model\Post\Field\Field;
use Dehaka\Model\Post\Field\GalleryField;
use Dehaka\Model\Post\Field\NumberField;
use Dehaka\Model\Post\Field\Price\PriceField;
use Dehaka\Model\Post\Field\Taxonomy\Taxonomy;
use WP_Post;

class RestApiManager extends Manager
{

    public function boot()
    {
        add_action('rest_api_init', [$this, 'registerFields']);

        add_action('rest_insert_' . Car::POST_TYPE, function (WP_Post $post, $request) {
            $meta = $request->get_param('meta');
            $car = new Car($post);

            dehakaApp('car_fields')
                ->filter(static function ($field) use ($meta) {
                    /* @var Field $field */
                    return !$field instanceof Taxonomy  && isset($meta[$field->getKey()]);
                })
                ->each(static function ($field) use ($car, $meta) {
                    $field->save($car, $meta[$field->getKey()]);
                });
        }, 10, 2);
    }

    public function registerFields()
    {
        foreach (dehakaApp('car_fields') as $field) {
            if ($field instanceof Taxonomy) {
                continue;
            }
            
            

            register_rest_field(Car::POST_TYPE, $field->getKey(), [
                'get_callback' => function ($post) use ($field) {
                    if (!$field instanceof GalleryField && !$field instanceof AttachmentsField && !$field instanceof PriceField) {
                        return get_post_meta($post['id'], $field->getKey(), true);
                    }

                    if ($field instanceof PriceField) {
                        $car = Car::getById($post['id']);
                        if (!$car) {
                            return [];
                        }

                        return $field->getValue($car);
                    }


                    $ids = explode(',', get_post_meta($post['id'], $field->getKey(), true));
                    if ($field instanceof GalleryField) {
                        $images = [];

                        foreach ($ids as $id) {
                            $imageUrl = wp_get_attachment_image_url($id, 'full');
                            if ($imageUrl) {
                                $images[] = $imageUrl;
                            }
                        }

                        return $images;
                    }

                    
                },
            ]);
        }
    }
```

###SOLUTION

I found the solution.
All i had to do was insert image id instead of image url in the "Imagefield". Hence as follows:

```
inputjson={"Taxonomy1":[445],"meta":{'field1':'55'},"Imagefield":<image id number>}
```

Comment: Can you try to send the imagefield value within a double inverted comma instead of a single inverted comma?

Comment: Didn't work. The api seem to be not accepting post request for this field(it seems to be a custom field). Anything unusual in the above code? particularly in relation to instances of GalleryField.

Comment: Does `$ids` have the expected value after the line `$ids = explode(',', get_post_meta($post['id'], $field->getKey(), true));`  ?

Comment: Yes, ids have the expected value. Only image and attachment field do not.

Comment: Should there be a update_callback? There's only get_callback above

Comment: Yes, @TheOracle, there should be a [`update_callback`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#adding-custom-fields-to-api-responses). Otherwise, the field would be read-only.

Comment: Are you by any chance working on a local server using localhost?

Comment: No im not using localhost

Comment: However, i found the solution, all i had to do was insert image id instead of image url in the "Imagefield". Hence as follows: {"Taxonomy1":[445],"meta":{'field1':'55'},"Imagefield":<imageid>}